# Syntax error from using spread operator in React project

Tags: reactjs, spread

```
const [meme, setMeme] = React.useState({
        topText: "",
        bottomText: "",
        randomImage: "http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg" 
})

setMeme(prevMeme => ({
            ...prevMeme,
            randomImage: url
}))
```

I'm following a course on scrimba about React and I can't use spread operator. I get this error: "ERROR in ./components/Meme.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: E:/memegenerator/components/Meme.js: Unexpected token (36:12)"

I tried looking for a solution and installed all of the following packs:
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-spread
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
but I still get this error.

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: This looks like a configuration error with your babel. Can you please delete node_modules and npm install?

Comment: My node version is v16.13.1
I deleted node_modules and used npm install but i still get this error